# Install mongodb driver in docker with dockerfile

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, docker, dockerfile

I have a mongodb docker container. I need another docker container which will have php and apache installed. I want to run a php script from this container and send some data to the mongodb container to save the data in mongodb database. So i need to install mongodb driver in the php-apache container.

To do that, i have created following dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
EXPOSE 80
```

It first builds php-apache docker image. Then it should install mongodb driver.

But when i run the following command

```
docker build -t my-mongo .
```

At one point it shows following message and stops the execution:

```
Need to get 2213 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9593 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What went wrong here? Is there anything wrong in the dockerfile ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What went wrong here? Is there anything wrong in the dockerfile ?

There are at least three things wrong with your Dockerfile IMO.

The first one is not in direct relation to your problem, but you are creating way too many layers (one for each `RUN` command) for something as simple as adding a driver to your image. You should put all this in a single layer (i.e. a single `RUN` command) and cleanup after yourself at the end to keep the layer footprint small.

Now the core of your real problem. As you can see in your output, `apt-get` is launched in interactive mode and asks for a confirmation. The docker build process can't handle that and therefore aborts the command causing the build to fail. To overcome this, `apt-get` has a `-y` option to answer 'yes' to all prompts by default.

The last one is in the line where you add the mongo driver to `php.ini`: you are redirecting echo output to your file with a single gt; sign (`>`), hence you are replacing the full content of the file you just copied. You must use a double gt; sign (`>>`) for content to be appended.

The following Dockerfile should fix the problems above (tested without the copy of sources + cp of your own php.ini file since I don't have them)

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    && pecl install mongodb \
    && cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EXPOSE 80
```

Some explanation:

- The `&&` notation allows to run all commands one after the other in a single docker `RUN` command resulting in a single intermediate container, thus a single layer.
- `-y --no-install-recommends` options to `apt-get` ask apt to not go interactive (answer yes everywhere) and to install only needed packages, not the recommended ones.
- The two last instruction `apt-get cleann && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` remove all caches made by running apt so that the layer stays as small as possible. (see [`apt-get` chapter in docker best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run))

Comment: thank you for your response. i found another issue. when i check phpinfo() on browser. it doesn't show mongodb loaded. Moreover, usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production is not copied to /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini. php.ini file has just one line - extension=mongodb.so. is there any further scope to improve the dockerfile ? my work is very simple. I just need to run a php script from this container and send data to the mongodb container.

Comment: Although this is actually an other issue and should be asked in a new question, it is quite trivial so I answered here. See my edit.

Comment: many thanks, but mongodb is still not shown in phpinfo() page

Comment: It is shown on my instance running from the image built from the Dockerfile above. Mongodb extension version 1.6.0

Comment: Not necessarily bad to have more than one layer. More layers can lead to faster image re-builds.

Comment: @spinkus I agree to your remark on a very general and theorical level and as long as all the process is optimized. But note that I was cautious enough to precise: `you are creating way too many layers.. for something as simple as adding a driver to your image`. In the context of the question, creating 5 layers where several are pure package cache updates without any cleanup (e.g. `apt-get update` on its own....) for simply adding a php mongodb driver is definitely a bad practice. If you can further optimize what I proposed above for this particular install, I'm happy to hear about it.

Answer (score -1):

put this at the beginning  of your Docker file, it is important to have it before installing all other extensions, otherwise it fails.

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade \
    && pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
```

That's all what I needed to get mongodb running `FROM` [php:7.3-cli-buster](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) Probably it will work for other versions - fpm, apache etc as well.

Comment: i tried your 2 lines at the beginning of dockerfile, but it shows error - Sending build context to Docker daemon  8.704kB
Error response from daemon: No build stage in current context

Comment: @A.Chy See edited Dockerfile - it works well for me, perhaps you have a problem due to different `FROM` - try `7.3-apache-buster` instead. Here's a [full list of supported tags](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/php/README.md#supported-tags-and-respective-dockerfile-links)

Comment: @A.Chy Try the docker file with only these three lines to build and once working add lines of the rest of your target Docker file and see what causes the error.

Comment: i tried it, but it shows the old problem. php.ini file not shown in /usr/local/etc/php folder

Comment: @A.Chy add the line `RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini`

Comment: now php.ini file is created and there is one line - extension=mongodb.so. but why mongodb is not shown in phpinfo() page ?

Comment: @A.Chy run docker image and log into its console `docker run -it --entrypoint="" your-image-name:latest bin/sh` and type `php -m` and you should see `mongodb` under the `[PHP Modules].`. Play with the php.ini and turn on/off some other extensions to see if it makes any difference. If you're using apache version of php image, make sure your PHP loads the ini file as you expect and not the different - check that [this way](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/phpini-file/)

Comment: i can see mongodb under the [PHP Modules]. but it's still not shown in phpinfo() page on browser.

Comment: i modified php.ini file like mysqli.reconnect = On/Off. but there is no effect on phpinfo() page on browser